# How to achieve R-21 insulation in 3.5 inch exterior wall

Tags: walls, insulation

I'd like to insulate an exterior 2x4 wall to R-21.  It looks like I'll need to use Rigid Foam of some sort.  I'm not finding any products at my local store which are 3.5 inches thick.  At the moment, I'm finding:

- Rmax Thermasheath-3 Polyisocyanurate at 2 inches which provides R-13.1
- Owens-corning Foamular XPS at 1.5 inches which provides R-7.5

*(that adds up to 20.6, which after considering the exterior wood and siding and the interior sheer wall, I should technically be at > R-21)*

Is this my best bet?  Simply put these two foams one on top of the other?  Is there a better system or single product I can buy in 3.5 inch thickness?  Should one or the other be on the outside?

Thanks for any advice, I'm new to insulation work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar wall that I insulated exactly (well, almost) the way you're describing.  Here's a cross section of the wall.  The left side is towards an unheated workshop.

[image]

I don't think I used 1.5 inch XPS because it would have caused the sheet rock to bulge slightly.

Another option is what they call an R13+5 construction.  With this technique, which can be used for new construction or when you're tearing down to the studs, fills the 3-1/2" wall cavity with something like Rockwool (R13), then fasten foam board insulation with an R-value of 5 to the outside of the wall, before your house wrap and siding.  The chart excerpt below is from a local building code information brochure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with spray foam, look carefully as they won't all meet your requirements which would be minimum R-6/inch. I found at least one, Tiger Foam which meets R-6/inch though.